# Given p→q is not tautology and q→p is not tautology so:

Tags: logic

1. p ∨ q is not tautology.
2. p ∨ q is tautology.
3. p ∧ q contradiction.
4. (p → q) → (q → p) is tautology.
5. All of the above are wrong.

I tried to use a truth table and I got (1) but apparently $q=f$ and $p=f$ cannot be in the truth table so the answer is not (1).
Can anyone explain why one is not the answer? and also, what is the correct answer?

Comment: $F\lor F\ne T $

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the Markdown code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Is this question from a quiz? I don't like it because it ostensibly requires the candidate to reason from the two given premises yet, as I was saying in its recent duplicate target [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480214/if-p-rightarrow-q-and-q-rightarrow-p-are-not-tautolgies-is-p-righta#comment9394630_4480214) and evidenced by Manx's answer below, the premises turn out to be redundant, in which case the candidate is left wondering whether they are *required* to use the two premises in their argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b$ be sentence letters.

> $1.$ Is it true that for any well formed formula $p,q$ say if $\not\vDash p\to q$ and $\not\vDash q\to p$ then $\not\vDash p \lor q?$

Consider $p:\equiv a$ and $q:\equiv\lnot a$ which gives $\not\vDash a\to \lnot a$ and $\not\vDash \lnot a\to a$ but $\vDash a \lor \lnot a$.

> $2.$ Is it true that for any well formed formula $p,q$ say if $\not\vDash p\to q$ and $\not\vDash q\to p$ then $\vDash p \lor q?$

Consider $p:\equiv a$ and $q:\equiv b$ which gives $\not\vDash a\to b$ and $\not\vDash b\to a$ but $\not\vDash a \lor b$.

> $3.$ Is it true that for any well formed formula $p,q$ say if $\not\vDash p\to q$ and $\not\vDash q\to p$ then $\vDash \lnot p \lor\lnot q?$

Consider $p:\equiv a$ and $q:\equiv b$ which gives $\not\vDash a\to b$ and $\not\vDash b\to a$ but $\not\vDash \lnot a \lor \lnot b$.

> $4.$ For any well formed formula $p,q$ say if $\not\vDash p\to q$ and $\not\vDash q\to p$ then $\vDash (p\to q)\to(q\to p)?$

Note that $(p\to q)\to(q\to p)\equiv p\lor\lnot q$.

Consider $p:\equiv a$ and $q:\equiv b$ which gives $\not\vDash a\to b$ and $\not\vDash b\to a$ but $\not\vDash a \lor \lnot b$.

Hence the right answer is

> $5.$ All of the above are wrong.

Comment: Out of curoisty, what does the double turnstile mean? I know that the regular turnstil means, "from $A$ I know $B$", $A \vdash B$. Tried looking on the internet about it, but didn't find much right off the bat.

Comment: @Michael $A\vdash B$ is the syntactic consequence means there is a deduction from $A$ to $B$. $A\vDash B$ is the semantic consequence means in every interpretation that $A$ is true we have $B$ is also true, and $\vDash A$ just means $A$ is true in every interpretation i.e. $A$ is a tautology.